# Pandas interpolate bools with the nearest method

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How to interpolate bool values in pandas using the nearest method?
The following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'b': np.random.rand(10) > 0.5})
df2 = df.iloc[[2,5,6,8]]
df2.reindex(df.index).interpolate('nearest')
```

Produces an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot interpolate with all NaNs.
```

Comment: Doesn't `df2.reindex(df.index, method='nearest')` work as intended?

Comment: it works. thank you. post is an answer and i'll accept it. why did my approach failed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Nickil Maveli's comment-answer use the following,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'b': np.random.rand(10) > 0.5})
df2 = df.iloc[[2,5,6,8]]
df2.reindex(df.index, method='nearest')
```

In answe to your question,

> why did my approach failed?

I believe this is to do with the fact that NaNs are `np.nan` and therefore are type floats. When using `reindex` it fills anything the would be a NaN before making it a NaN. Using your original method therefore creates a mixed array of `float` and `bool`*.

See how we can interpolate on just `bool`

```
df2.reindex(df.index).astype(bool).interpolate('nearest')

Out[1]:

    b
0   True
1   True
2   True
3   True
4   True
5   False
6   False
7   True
8   False
9   True
```

or with just `float`

```
df2.reindex(df.index).astype(float).interpolate('nearest')

Out[2]:

    b
0   NaN
1   NaN
2   1.0
3   1.0
4   1.0
5   1.0
6   0.0
7   0.0
8   0.0
9   NaN
```

Notice that the `bool` behaves rather unexpectedly as it fills the NaNs with `True`. Therefore the original answer seems to work most efficiently.

---

*This isn't quite inline with what the error message says so I could be a little off but I think the general concept is correct.